# Erro em os.system() python

Tags: python, sistema-operacional

Tenho um script em python que precisa executar outro software múltiplas vezes, estou tentando fazer isso utilizando os.system("command"), mas essa função sempre me retorna -1 e não funciona, já testei inclusive com comandos simples.

PS estou utilizando python 2.7

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Overflow em Português! Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema. Está demasiado ampla a sua pergunta, veja na [Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Qual sistema operacional você está tentando executar seu script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma outra rotina de Python, chamada [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module).

Ela evita muitos problemas relacionados com aspas e convenções entre os diferentes shells dos sistemas operacionais. O comando é passado utilizando uma lista, ao invés de uma string, sendo o primeiro elemento o comando e os próximos os parâmetros.

Exemplo

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['Notepad.exe', 'C:\\temp\\test.txt'])
```